# Booting up issues stemming from dual boot installation process

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

Was trying to install ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS to dual boot alongside win10. Followed along some articles/stack overflow posts about how to go about it. Have a ~5 year old PC, I *believe* using UEFI, HD is a 256g SSD. Shrank the win10 partition to free up space, created a linux boot usb, and ran the installer. Had to use the "something else" option (wasnt given the install alongside windows option). Tried a few different things because I was getting errors during installation. Last thing I tried, based off a stackoverflow post, I had created 3 partitions: /home, a swap, and an EFI partition. Installed to the /home partition, and when it asked what device to install the boot loader to, I chose the SSD (seemed to get installation errors choosing anything else). Had been wary about doing this, previously had chosen particular partitions to try installing to, but since I was getting errors during installation otherwise, I went ahead and tried it based on one of the SO post suggestions. Installation completed, but now cant get the computer to boot and just get an error message of "reboot and select proper boot device". Not exactly sure what the issue is -- tried some MBR repair steps but that doesnt seem to do anything, tried deleting the EFI partition, also didnt fix things. Im guessing the boot loader or MBR or something is screwed up, just not exactly sure how to fix it. I havent deleted the win10 partition -- I can see it still there when running diskpart from a win10 recovery usb for example, I just cant seem to get it to boot into it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If it is running in UEFI mode and you deleted the EFI partition you have screwed up your Windows installation. If it didn’t offer you an install alongside option you probably installed Ubuntu in legacy mode. That will not work with Windows in UEFI mode. I guess you have two choices, either reinstall Windows and then Ubuntu or fix Windows and then install Ubuntu. Either way you should follow this when installing https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI It’s probably simpler to reinstall both but backup any data you cannot afford to lose first.